# Limit what triggers an htmx request

Tags: htmx

Expected behavior is when focused on the name input in the form, hitting enter should submit the form. What actually happens is that it triggers the X button to remove the website input. Clicking enter again calls the add website button to bring it back, and continues to toggle it when clicking enter.

```html
<form action="/api/test" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input
        type="text"
        id="name" 
        name="name"
    />
    
    <label>Websites:</label>
    <div id="websites">
        <div id="website-{{.WebsiteId}}" class="flex my-2">
            <input 
                type="text" 
                name="website-{{.WebsiteId}}" 
            />
            <button hx-swap="delete" hx-trigger="click" 
                    hx-target="#website-{{.WebsiteId}}" 
                    hx-get="/input/website">X</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button hx-get="/input/website" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#websites" 
            hx-swap="beforeend">Add Website</button>
    <div class="flex sm:flex-row flex-col">
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Video of what is happening on enter click:

> [image: Video of what is happening on enter click]

I've tried adding the `hx-trigger="click"` to all the elements that have an htmx request on it. I was hoping that this would limit the requests to just a mouse click, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `type="button"` to first two buttons.

What happens is when you don't define button type, the form assumes it's of submit type by default, hence your issue.